# How to avoid namespaces when declaring explicitly a Controller in a Resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I want:

```
url: /admin/site/items/:item_id/assets/index(.:format) 
controller: admin/assets#index
```

If I declare the route in a simple way:

```
namespace :admin do
  namespace :site do
    resources :items do
      resources :assets
    end
  end
end
```

I obtain the next route/controller connection:

```
url: /admin/site/items/:item_id/assets/index(.:format)
controller: admin/site/assets#index
```

If I try to expecify explictly the `controller` like this:

```
namespace :admin do
  namespace :site do
    resources :items do
      resources :assets, :controller => "admin/assets"
    end
  end
end
```

Then I obtain this:

```
url: /admin/site/items/:item_id/assets/index(.:format) 
controller: admin/site/admin/assets#index
```

I have also tried to add an initial `/` to the route of the controller like this

```
resources :assets, :controller => "/admin/assets"
```

But is even worst:

```
url: /admin/site/items/:item_id/assets/index(.:format) 
controller: admin/site//admin/assets#index
```

I want this behavior because I have an `AssetsController` that is in charge of the manipulation of the `Assets` of different `Models` in my application. And there are several namespaces but I want the `AssetsController` to remain in the lowerst one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think what you want is possible with nested resources declarations. Here's another option to try:

```
namespace :admin do
  namespace :site do
    resources :items
  end

  scope "/site/items/:item_id" do
    resources :assets, :as => "site_item_assets"
  end
end
```

(see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing, or http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing.html)

Comment: You obtain the correct _url/controller_ for the resource `assets`: `/admin/site/items/:item_id/assets(.:format) => admin/assets#index` but you lost the correct _controller_ for the resource `items` with is now targeting `admin/items#index` instead the correct one which is `admin/site/items#index`.

Comment: Ah, I did not realize that the items controller was namespaced. Edited my suggestion above.

Comment: Now both controllers are namespaced `admin/site/assets#index` `admin/site/items#index`

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure that would work. I think what you're trying to do just goes too far outside the rails conventions; you'll want to use two different blocks. I'll give you another alternative above, in an edit

Comment: It works!, I just have edited your answer to add a proper _url name_ because if not it will be just `admin_assets` and due there are multiple _main resources_ I have to difference the urls by resource.

Answer (score 0):

What about trying:

```
namespace :admin do
  scope :module => "site" do
    resources :items do
      resources :assets
    end
  end
end
```

Tell me how that works out for you

Comment: The only thing that changes with this is the _name_ of the route, instead of `admin_site_item_assets` I have `admin_item_assets`. The _url_ and the _controller_ remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround splitting the routes in two blocks, one for the routes of the main resource `items` and the other for the nested resource `assets`:

```
# routes for the main resource
namespace :admin do
  namespace :site do
    resources :items
  end
end

# routes for the nested resource
namespace :admin do
  resources :items, :only => [], :path => "/site/items"
    resources :assets
  end
end
```

See how I have passed `:only => []` to avoid the creation of *default routes* in the second block.

Passing the `:path` option I obtain the *url* looks like I like.

The only problem with this approach is that the names of the routes are losing the *site* prefix:

```
admin_site_item_assets => admin_item_assets
```

I have tried to use the `:as => "site_items"` option in the `items` resource but this changes the *url* itself:

```
/admin/site/items/:item_id/assets(.:format) => /admin/site/items/:site_item_id/assets(.:format)
```

And the *url* is more important to me than the *route name*.